# Creating One to Many relation in JPA Spring

Tags: spring, jpa

I would like to link a comment table and a film table with a user table. I wish to allow a user to have many comments, and a film have many comments. I then want to display a list of comments in a details page for each film, giving the option for the user who created the comment to delete or update it.

I altered my code in an attempt to create a one to many relation between comment and film, but I get the error:

> Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: NULL not allowed for column
>   "FILM_ID"; SQL statement: alter table film add column film_id bigint
>   not null [23502-196]

It makes me think two things:

1) Set to allow null or figure out why there is a null field. I attempted allow null by adding `@Column(name = "film_id", nullable = true)` but it said parameter is redundant.

2) Film table has auto incrementing ID already, so by adding `@Column(name = "film_id")` am I duplicating an ID? As with the error message saying "add column" it made me think so?

My attempt currently stands at:

Film.java

```
package com.demo.spring.domain;

import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

@Entity
public class Film {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "film_id", nullable = true)
    Long id;

    String title;
    String director;
    String description;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date date;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "film_id", referencedColumnName = "film_id")
    List<Comment> comments;


    public List<Comment> getComments() {
        return comments;
    }

    public void setComments(List<Comment> comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }


    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
//rest of getter and setters below//
```

Comment.java

```
package com.demo.spring.domain;

import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    Long id;

    String body;

    @Column(name = "film_id")
    Long filmId;

    public Long getFilmId() {
        return filmId;
    }

    public void setFilmId(Long filmId) {
        this.filmId = filmId;
    }

    public Comment(){

    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getBody() {
        return body;
    }

    public void setBody(String body) {
        this.body = body;
    }

}
```

UPDATE

I have changed Film.java..

From:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "film_id", referencedColumnName = "film_id")
List<Comment> comments;
```

To:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
List<Comment> comments;
```

And if I add in Comment.java:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

@JoinTable(name="film", joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name = "film_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "film_id"))

private Set<Comment> comment = new HashSet<Comment>();
Film film;
```

I get:

> MappingException: Foreign key
>   (FK5vk85sy54a8be115ye9ra1lyu:film_comments [film_film_id])) must have
>   same number of columns as the referenced primary key (film
>   [film_id_fk,comment_comment_id])

If I change `private Set<Comment> comment = new HashSet<Comment>();` to `List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();` I get:

> NULL not allowed for column "FILM_ID"; SQL statement: alter table film
>   add column film_id bigint not null

And if instead I add:

```
@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)

@JoinColumn(name = "film_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "film_id")

private Set<Comment> comment = new HashSet<Comment>();
Film film;
```

I get:

> MappingException: Could not determine type for:
>   com.demo.spring.domain.Film, at table: comment, for columns:
>   [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(film)]

If I change `private Set<Comment> comment = new HashSet<Comment>();` to `List<Comment> comments = new ArrayList<Comment>();` I get:

> NULL not allowed for column "FILM_ID"; SQL statement: alter table film
>   add column film_id bigint not null

Answer (score 1):

A primary key can't be null, so you can't make `"film_id"` nullable. And your `@JoinColumn` annotation is wrong, that goes on the `@ManyToOne` side. The `name` parameter should be the name of the foreign key column in the `Comments` table (so it can't be the same name as the primary key) and `referencedColumnName` should be the name of the column that you're referencing in the other table

```
@Entity
public class Film {

    @Id @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "film_id")
    Long id;

    String title;
    String director;
    String description;
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")
    Date date;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    List<Comment> comments;

    //...

}

@Entity
public class Comment {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "comment_id")
    Long id;

    String body;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "film_id_fk", referencedColumnName = "film_id")
    Film film;

    //...

}
```

Comment: Thank you that makes sense. However I get the following errors after this update: "Unable to map collection com.demo.spring.domain.Film.comments" & "Unable to find column with logical name: comment_id in org.hibernate.mapping.Table(film)"

Comment: My mistake, I mixed up the annotations. The FK should be on the `@ManyToOne` side

Comment: That cleared those errors but replaced with:  "NULL not allowed for column "FILM_ID"; SQL statement:
alter table film add column film_id bigint not null". It doesnt seem right that it is adding film_id to film table? And the null issue still. It is same as original error :(

Comment: Does the schema match the annotations? Try regenerating it with Hibernate. If it still doesn't work, try removing the `referencedColumnName` from Comment and adding `mappedBy = "film"` on Film's `@OneToMany` annotation

Comment: If I do that I get: "mappedBy reference an unknown target entity property: com.demo.spring.domain.Comment.film in com.demo.spring.domain.Film.comments". I updated my question with other code I have tried and varying error messages. I hope they help to solve this. I thought i was getting close when it referenced foreign keys.